# How to exit while loop on certain condition and exception handling for invalid values

Tags: c#, arrays, while-loop, try-catch, sentinel

This is homework, so I'm just looking for some guidance. I have my code working to return a value in an array[10] based on an index value given by the user.

What isn't working is that I need to stop the program when "99" is entered, a value that also triggers the try-catch IndexOutOfRangeException. I can't get the program to recognize the difference between "99" and any other out of range value. I did try it with an if-else, but "99" still threw the IndexOutOfRangeException and it wouldn't loop. An attempt at do-while also didn't work.

Code is below. Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

class SubscriptExceptionTest
{
static void Main()
{
    double[] array = {20.3, 44.6, 32.5, 46.7, 89.6, 67.5, 12.3, 14.6, 22.1, 13.6};

    int i = 0;

    while (i != 99)
        try
        {

            Write("Enter a number to see the value in that position. Type 99 to stop: ");
            i = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

            double arrayVal = array[i];
            WriteLine("The value at index {0} is {1}", i, arrayVal);
            ReadLine();
        }
        catch (FormatException fe)
        {
            throw new FormatException("You did not enter an integer.");
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ie)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index was outside the bounds of the array.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is once you are catching `IndexOutOfRangeException` you are again throwing it inside the `catch` block which is not handled anywhere in the code.

The other problem is that you are not checking for the value of `i` for 99  before using it for accessing it in the array which leads to Exception.

See below -

```
int i = 0;

while (i != 99)
    try
                {

                    Write("Enter a number to see the value in that position. Type 99 to stop: ");
                    i = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
                    if(i == 99) {
                      Console.WriteLine("Thanks!!, Breaking here!!!");
                      break;
                    }
                    double arrayVal = array[i];
                    WriteLine("The value at index {0} is {1}", i, arrayVal);
                    ReadLine();
                }

                catch (FormatException fe)
                {
                    throw new FormatException("You did not enter an integer.");
                }

                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ie)
                {
                    // Show some message here
                }

}
```

Comment: The grading software is still burping on the if statement but it works in Visual Studio, and that's good enough for me. Thank you! The placement of the if statement was the issue. Sometimes it's really hard for this human to think like a computer.

Answer (score 0):

Put an if construct to check for value 99 and exit the application if the condition is true.

```
i = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

if( i == 99 )
{
    //Perform any operation you want to before exiting the application.
    Console.WriteLine("Exiting Application");

    //This will terminate the program.
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, Try/Catch's and **Exception Handlers should only be used Exceptionally**. They are expensive. Let me show you how to handle these issues using defensive programming.

I think using the Array.Length to check the Array Bounds if *any other out of range value* is the answer you want.

```
static void Main()
{
double[] array = {20.3, 44.6, 32.5, 46.7, 89.6,67.5, 12.3, 14.6, 22.1, 13.6};

int i = 0;

while (i != 99)
{
        Write("Enter a number to see the value in that position. Type 99 to stop: ");

        var result = ReadLine();

        bool isInteger = int.TryParse(result, out i);

        if (isInteger == false) throw new FormatException("You did not enter an integer.");

        if (i == 99) Environment.Exit(0);

        if (i < 0 || i > array.Length) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index was outside the bounds of the array.");

        double arrayVal = array[i];

        WriteLine("The value at index {0} is {1}", i, arrayVal);

        ReadLine();    
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful. As a student programmer, I have to meet the requirements of the assignment, but I very much appreciate you taking the time to demonstrate something like this in a "real world" scenario.

Comment: Anticipate problems, go after bug's like a dog after a bone, get good at Debugging!!! Best advice, read a couple of books. Compliment that with tutorials & a tutor. Good luck!!